# How do I 'filter in' firestore data satisfying 'contains' condition?

Tags: firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

[image: I just want to retrieve data according to node "City". Have a look to this image]

```
Query query = fireStore.collection("Requests").whereEqualTo("City",Noida);
```

this query work when City node has the exact value ("Noida in this case") but I want to retrieve all data where "City" containing require data

for example:
when City = Noida
this case is working.
What I want to do is

when City= Noida sec-32
and If I type Noida it still searches Noida sec-32

Comment: Have you tried utilizing ["array-contains-any"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any)? This always filters by the array data type.

Comment: no, that a different thing, this provides me a value from every node in firebase with same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no query in Firestore that queries substrings as you want.

But there is a workaround for small datasets,which consists in to query all the data and save in a variable ( In your case, getting all the cities name ) and use `contains()` method like this:

```
Query query = fireStore.collection("Requests");
String str1 = document.getString("City");
String str2 = "Noida";
boolean b = str1.toLowerCase().contains(str2.toLowerCase());
```

And if you print the value of b, if it matches it will return true, if not false. But the above examples works well enough only for **small** datasets, as it's not efficient for big datasets. In this case, as the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search) recommends, you can enable full text search of your Cloud Firestore data, using a third-party search service like [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/).

Comment: thanks for your time. How many data entries are you considering in a small dataset?

Comment: This only works for small datasets because the complexity is n^2, so if you have 1000 elements, the complexity will be 1000000. According to me, less than 100 elements will be considered as small datasets as it will have the complexity of 100 000 reads.

Comment: Ok, now I get the logic. Thank you

Comment: Could you please accept my answer if it was useful for you.

Comment: Ohh sorry for that, can you also please mark this question up if you think this can help other

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so you can implement this directly. But I can suggest you a way to do. You can add another field to the document like *"sector"*
in which you can store the suburb of the city.

> For eg. you can have city = "noida" and sector = "sector 32".

Like this you can query for city and then get the sector
too.